# Use continuity to evaluate the limit. #2

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, continuity

Use continuity to evaluate the limit.

$$\lim_{x\to 3} \arctan\left(\frac{x^2-9}{5x^2-15x}\right)$$
Factored and got...
$$\lim_{x\to 3} \arctan\left(\frac{x+3}{5x}\right)$$
Then...
$$\lim_{x\to 3} \arctan\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)$$
Then...my decimal evaluation of $0.5404195$ radians does not solve the problem?

Comment: $\dfrac{3+3}{5\times3}=$.?

Comment: you made an arithmetic mistake going from 2nd to 3rd expression

Comment: Pick up $\lim$ in last expression.

Comment: That still won't give you an exact, nice-looking decimal expansion for the result; but $\arctan\frac{2}{5}$ **is** a closed-form, valid answer. The decimal expansion of a number is just one way to write it. (If the answer were $1/3$, for instance, would you doubt it because $0.333333\dots$ is not exact?)

Comment: @ClementC. I'm using webassign software to plug in my answers and it's confused because the way I put in the answer so it did get my little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\arctan$ is continuous in $\mathbf R$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to 3} \arctan\left(\frac{x+3}{5x}\right)\stackrel{!}{=} \arctan \left(\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x+3}{5x}\right)= \arctan \left(\frac{2}{5} \right).$$ 
You just calculated the last limit wrong.